# Memory growing out of control when loading users photo album in UICollecitonView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, phasset, photosframework

I am loading the photos from a users photo album into a collection view similar to how is done  in [this Apple Sample project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/browsing_and_modifying_photo_albums?language=objc). I can not seem to track down why the memory is growing out of control. I use the suggested [PHCachingImageManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phcachingimagemanager) but all that results are blurry images, freezing scrolling and memory growing out of control until the application crashes.

**In my `viewDidLoad` I run the code below**

```
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status: PHAuthorizationStatus) in
            print("photo authorization status: \(status)")
            if status == .authorized && self.fetchResult == nil {
                print("authorized")

                let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
                fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
                var tempArr:[PHAsset] = []
                self.fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)

                guard let fetchResult = self.fetchResult else{
                    print("Fetch result is empty")
                    return
                }

                fetchResult.enumerateObjects({asset, index, stop in
                    tempArr.append(asset)
                })
//                self.assets = tempArr

                self.imageManager.startCachingImages(for: tempArr, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil)

                tempArr.removeAll()
                print("Asset count after initial fetch: \(self.assets?.count)")

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // Reload collection view once we've determined our Photos permissions.
                    print("inside of main queue reload")
                    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self)
                    self.collectionView.delegate = self
                    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                print("photo access denied")
                self.displayPhotoAccessDeniedAlert()
            }
        }
```

and inside of `cellForItemAt:` I run the following code

**`cellForItemAt`**

```
  guard let fetchResult = self.fetchResult else{
            print("Fetch Result is empty")
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = false
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
        //let scale = min(2.0, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        let targetSize = CGSize(width: cell.bounds.width * scale, height: cell.bounds.height * scale)

//        let asset = assets[indexPath.item]
        let asset = fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.item)
        let assetIdentifier = asset.localIdentifier

        cell.representedAssetIdentifier = assetIdentifier

        imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: cell.frame.size,
                                              contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions) { (image, hashable)  in
                                                if let loadedImage = image, let cellIdentifier = cell.representedAssetIdentifier {

                                                    // Verify that the cell still has the same asset identifier,
                                                    // so the image in a reused cell is not overwritten.
                                                    if cellIdentifier == assetIdentifier {
                                                        cell.imageView.image = loadedImage
                                                    }
                                                }
        }
```

Comment: Caching for `PHImageManagerMaximumSize` doesn’t seem very memory friendly.  Why so large for cells?

Comment: @WarrenBurton I am using the mosaic grid layout shown from this apple sample project https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/customizing_collection_view_layouts I want to get the photos to load so they aren't blurry so I figured making the target size larger would help but it didn't.  In any event I tried setting the size to be 1/3 the width of the screen but the memory problem still seems to exist. Any Ideas?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem this week using the Apple Code which for others reference is available here [Browsing & Modifying Photos](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/browsing_and_modifying_photo_albums)

Memory usage was very high, and then if viewing a single item and returning to root, memory would spike and the example would crash.

As such from our experiments there were a few tweaks which improved performance.

Firstly when setting the thumbnailSize for the requestImage function:

```
open func requestImage(for asset: PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode, options: PHImageRequestOptions?, resultHandler: @escaping (UIImage?, [AnyHashable : Any]?) -> Void) -> PHImageRequestID
```

We set the scale like so instead of using the full size:

```
UIScreen.main.scale * 0.75
```

We also set the `PHImageRequestOptions Resizing Mode` to `.fast`.

As well as this we found that setting the following variables of the `CollectionViewCell` also helped somewhat:

```
layer.shouldRasterize = true
layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
isOpaque = true
```

We also noticed that the `updateCachedAssets()` in the `ScrollViewwDidScroll` method was playing some part in this process so we removed that from this callback(rightly or wrongly).

And one final thing was the we kept a reference to the `PHCachingImageManager` for each cell and if it existed then we called:

```
open func cancelImageRequest(_ requestID: PHImageRequestID)
```

As such here is the code for our `MediaCell`:

```
extension MediaCell{

  /// Populates The Cell From The PHAsset Data
  ///
  /// - Parameter asset: PHAsset
  func populateCellFrom(_ asset: PHAsset){

    livePhotoBadgeImage = asset.mediaSubtypes.contains(.photoLive) ? PHLivePhotoView.livePhotoBadgeImage(options: .overContent) : nil

    videoDuration = asset.mediaType == .video ? asset.duration.formattedString() : ""

    representedAssetIdentifier = asset.localIdentifier
  }


  /// Shows The Activity Indicator When Downloading From The Cloud
  func startAnimator(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.activityIndicator.isHidden = false
      self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }
  }


  /// Hides The Activity Indicator After The ICloud Asset Has Downloaded
  func endAnimator(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
      self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
  }

}

final class MediaCell: UICollectionViewCell, Animatable {

  @IBOutlet private weak var imageView: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet private weak var livePhotoBadgeImageView: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet private weak var videoDurationLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!{
    didSet{
      activityIndicator.isHidden = true
    }
  }

  var representedAssetIdentifier: String!
  var requestIdentifier: PHImageRequestID!

  var thumbnailImage: UIImage! {
    didSet {
      imageView.image = thumbnailImage
    }
  }

  var livePhotoBadgeImage: UIImage! {
    didSet {
      livePhotoBadgeImageView.image = livePhotoBadgeImage
    }
  }

  var videoDuration: String!{
    didSet{
     videoDurationLabel.text = videoDuration
    }
  }

  //----------------
  //MARK:- LifeCycle
  //----------------

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    isOpaque = true
  }

  override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    imageView.image = nil
    representedAssetIdentifier = ""
    requestIdentifier = nil
    livePhotoBadgeImageView.image = nil
    videoDuration = ""
    activityIndicator.isHidden = true
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
  }

}
```

And the code for the `cellForItem`:

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let asset = dataViewModel.assettAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mediaCell", for: indexPath) as! MediaCell

    if let requestID = cell.requestIdentifier { imageManager.cancelImageRequest(requestID) }

    cell.populateCellFrom(asset)

    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.resizeMode = .fast
    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

    options.progressHandler = { (progress, error, stop, info) in

      if progress == 0.0{
        cell.startAnimator()
      } else if progress == 1.0{
        cell.endAnimator()
      }
    }

    cell.requestIdentifier = imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: thumbnailSize,
                                                       contentMode: .aspectFill, options: options,
                                                       resultHandler: { image, info in

                                                        if cell.representedAssetIdentifier == asset.localIdentifier {

                                                          cell.thumbnailImage = image


                                                        }

    })

    return cell
  }
```

One additional area is in the updateCachedAssets() funtion. You are using:

```
self.imageManager.startCachingImages(for: tempArr, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil)
```

It would probably be best to set a smaller size here e.g:

```
imageManager.startCachingImages(for: addedAssets,
                                targetSize: thumbnailSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil)
```

Whereby thumbnail size e.g:

```
/// Sets The Thumnail Image Size
private func setupThumbnailSize(){

let scale = isIpad ? UIScreen.main.scale : UIScreen.main.scale * 0.75
let cellSize = collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize
thumbnailSize = CGSize(width: cellSize.width * scale, height: cellSize.height * scale)

}
```

All of these tweaks helped to ensure that the memory usage remained fair constant, and in our testing ensured that there were no exceptions thrown.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for very thorough answer and for all of your advise after implementing your suggestions I am still seeing the memory growing and the photos are still blurry however I will say that there was a much faster load time and the activity indicator was a nice touch. Im not sure what else to do what do you recommend could it be some kind of bug in the Photos Library. Is there some type of memory leak. Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries, I added one additional tweak which I forgot at the end ^_____^. And yes, I think there is some kind of bug here.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help. Im running it on an iPhone I tried setting the scale to be the same across all the cells I scaled them to 1/3 size of the screen so I 1/3 width multiplied by the 0.75 as the thumbnail size. Do you think this could be related to iOS 13, maybe the updates made to the photos app? This just started giving me trouble now with the blurry pictures, slow response and excessive memory use. Im not sure what to try next?

Comment: I can't say for sure. At our end it all works fine now :) Sorry I can't be of anymore help :(

Comment: @TheRedCamaro3.03.0 looks like caching is not the best way for fast scroll at all

Comment: also note that **shouldRasterize** property for layer is not optimal solution if you redraw the layer often

Comment: @GringoRusso You are 100% correct we wound up not using the PHImageCahceManager. The performance turned out to be quite disappointing over all.

Comment: and also try delete collectionView `deinit { collectionView = nil } `